# How to make React Native TextInput keep text after screen change

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am making an app which contains a notes field which needs to keep its input after the screen changes, but it always resets after you leave the page. Here is my constructor for the state:

```
this.state = {text: ""};
```

And my textinput declaration:

```
<TextInput
                    style={{
                        height: 200,
                        width: 250,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                    }}

                    editable = {true}
                    multiline = {true}
                    numberofLines = {4}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                    value={this.state.text}
                />
```

I've been trying to find a way to set the state to a variable that doesn't get reinitialized on opening the page up but have no luck so far. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AsyncStorage` to persist the input value. For eg:

```
<TextInput
  style={{
    height: 200,
    width: 250,
    fontSize: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  }}
  editable = {true}
  multiline = {true}
  numberofLines = {4}
  onChangeText={(text) => { 
    this.setState({text});
    AsyncStorage.setItem('inputKey', text); // Note: persist input
  }}
  value={this.state.text}
 />
```

Then inside componentDidMount you can check for the value and update state accordingly to reinitialise with old value.

```
componentDidMount() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('inputKey').then((value) => {
    if (value !== null){
    // saved input is available
    this.setState({ text: value }); // Note: update state with last entered value
  }
  }).done();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you leave the page in certain type of navigation you trigger the "componentUnmount" and it get destroy and rebuild when you come back.

You have to store your data away from your component class. In an other class for example. A class with only one instance

```
...

let instance = null;

class OtherClass {
  constructor() {
    if(instance) {
      return instance;
    }

    instance = this;
  }
...
}
```

So when your user make an input save the content in that "OtherClass" and then each time you rebuild your parent component, you set the value with data previously store here.

Each time you initialize that class the content wont be erase because it will always take the previous instance.

Hope it help !